# How to complete Lost Horatio Quest?

Tags: endless-space-2

I've taken the lost ship to my planet with +3 free population slots.  But the population have not come onto the planet yet.  I've put the ship in my hangar.  What else should I do?  Is it correct that there should be 3 new population added to the system?

Comment: I found [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/392110/discussions/0/1291816569122265117/) not-so-clear Steam discussion that seems to imply you might need to to bring the ship to a system that has space on a Mediterranean system, which is the Horatio ideal system. I don't know if this will actually complete it or not, but if you try it and it does, then I'll form an answer. Also, the [Endless Space 2 Wiki](http://endless-space-2.wikia.com/wiki/Quests#Multiple_Parts) indicates the rewards are: 50 Influence, an exploration ship, and 1 population unit of [faction].